# How can I start the Python Shell or the Python IDLE through WindowsFormsHost?

Tags: c#

I want to start the Python Shell or IDLE as a child process of my WPF C# application using WindowsFormsHost.

For other applications it works just fine, but as the shell don't have a GUI so it gives problems.

I'm starting those other applications with this code:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "/path/to/file.exe";
p.Start();

p.WaitForInputIdle();
while (p.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero) {
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    p.Refresh(); 
}
SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, panel.Handle);
```

But `p.WaitForInputHandle()` gives some error about not having a graphical interface for the Python Shell.

So I thought that the IDLE is a graphical interface!
It isn't an executable, though. I found out that there are a .py and a .bat file to start it or through Python code.

I tried to start it through code:

```
if (!File.Exists(path)) {
    string prg = @"import idlelib.idle
idlelib.idle.main()";

    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path);
    sw.Write(prg);
    sw.Close();
}

Process p = new Process();

p.StartInfo.FileName = "python.exe";
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; 
p.StartInfo.Arguments = path; 
p.Start();
```

I'm not sure if this is correct.

For now the python code is interpreted and the IDLE is started in the background of my application and as a standalone app.
I don't know how to set it as the son of the WindowsFormsHost.

Comment: You need full path of the python.exe file.  The process class has no environmental variables like path so you must specify the path.  Also which I think is the root cause of your issue is the child py file also does not have a PATH so any files referenced by the py must also have the path.  The py file usually will get the location of the files where the py is located, but if the referenced files in py are in a different folder then you have an issue.  Also depending on version Ironpython you may be limited to filename lengths of ~120 characters.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'm not using IronPython, I'm just writing into a file and then execute it. I will use the full path of the python.exe, even if this is working fine. The problem is that when I open the IDLE from the Python Shell, it isn't a WindowsFormsHost child. How could I set it as that?

Comment: When you do not have a path everything becomes relative to where the c# executable is located and where the Python Shell is located.  So you have tow choices 1) Put the python Shell in the same folder as the c# executable.  And then place any files that the python shell is calling also in the C# executable folder.  If the shell is looking for additional files in shell child/parent/sibling folder then these files also have to be moved. 2) Put the Python Shell (and additional files) in a foreign location.  Then  use the full path of the python shell in the call from the c# process class.

Comment: I am now using the full path of my python install. The application closes executing `SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, panel.Handle);`, though. Instead, if I add `MoveWindow(p.MainWindowHandle, 45, 20, 425, 300, true);` after that function the shell appears but I can only write the first time not being able to reselect it and interact with it.

Comment: How long should it take for the python to complete?  I think the same issue is occurring using SetParent and MoveWindow.  What is p.MainWindowHandle after python executes?  I'm wondering if it is -1.  What library are you using for SetParent?  Why do you need to Set Parent?

Comment: Since running the shell to open IDLE is one more step I'm thinking of interacting directly with the shell. I'm using SetParent (comes directly from `user32.dll`) to set the process as the child of the WindowsFormsHost.

Comment: Why do you need SetParent?????  It will automatically be a child of the form since you are using Process Class.

Comment: You can't expect this to work. Cross process parent child relationships require a lot of cooperation and you only control one side of the relationship.

Comment: I need it to be a son of panel, I guess, otherwise it doesn't work. @DavidHeffernan how could I start a python shell and set it as a WindowsFormsHost child?

Comment: You probably can't. For the reasons I outlined above.